# mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have installed phpmyadmin and while login am getting following error in mac os catalina 10.15.5

**mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Socket operation on non-socket**

Comment: PHP version? Connector/C version? How is phpmyadmin configured to connect to the database? What database version? Welcome to SO.

Comment: Get same message after failed log-in either as 'root' (or my username) with password I created

PHP 7.3.11
mysql 15.1
I tried altering config file (adding blowfish thing-y). 
Tried installing mysql with Strong Password Encryption and legacy encryption. 
The answer at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984698/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-macos-catalina got me to a config/setup page, but failed with the same message attempting to log in as root with the password I created.

B.

Comment: Can you connect from the MySQL command line client?

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed this issue by changing "localhost" ->"127.0.0.1" in config file of phpmyadmin